# writing files with fstream doesnt work in c++

Tags: c++, file

I want to do some checks before I write something to my file. Writing does not work when I make these checks. What could be the reason for this?

The checking process works like this. Is the data entered by the user in the file?
If there is a simpler way to check this I can try that too.

Working code:

```
void add_dealer(){
    file.open("center.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    c.new_Dealer();
    file.write((char*)&c,sizeof(Center));
    file.close();
    cout << "The dealer has been saved.";
}
```

After doing the checking:

```
fstream file;

bool check_dealer_name(string name){
    bool result = false;
    file.open("center.txt", ios::in);
    while(file.read((char*)&c,sizeof(Center))){
        if(c.getLocation()== name){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
bool check_dealer_id(int id){
    bool result = false;
    while(file.read((char*)&c,sizeof(Center))){
        if(c.getID() == id){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
void add_dealer(){
    c.new_Dealer();
    file.open("center.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (!check_dealer_id(c.getID()) || !check_dealer_name(c.getLocation())){
        file.write((char*)&c,sizeof(Center));
        file.close();
        cout << "The dealer has been saved.";
    }
    else{
        cout << "This Dealer name or dealer id already exists" << endl;
    }
    file.close();

}
```

Class:

```
class Center{
    int ID;
    char location[50];
public:
    void new_Dealer(){
        cout << "Enter the Dealer ID: " ;
        cin >> ID; 
        cout << endl << "Enter the Dealer location: ";
        cin >> location;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot read and write objects like this, you have to serialize and deserialize them.

Comment: @spectras This is not true. Look at the class definition, it's perfectly ok for binary reading and writing.

Comment: @john> I read a bit fast, indeed that specific class should work. It's easy to get unusable files that way though.

Comment: @john: Look a third time. The class is _not_ perfectly ok for binary reading and writing, due to padding issues(assuming `sizeof(int)==4`). Reading and writing those is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you fail to close the file after your checks. You can't open a file using a variable that already has the file open.

This error is only possible because you are reusing the same `file` variable for different purposes. I **strongly** recommend that you declare the file variable separately in each method that needs to use it. That way the `fstream` destructor will automatically close the file at the end of the function and the error you made would be impossible.

Comment: Could you explain with the code. I could not understand

Comment: @ZengaHivo To show you some code I would need to see the code where you call `check_dealer_name` and `check_dealer_id`.

Comment: @ZengaHivo But here's the quick explanation. When you are checking the dealer, you are reading the file. Then you call `add_dealer` where you are writing the file. In between those two you must close the file `file.close()`, you cannot open a file that is already open if you use the same variable for both occasions.